# How to determine changing scale factors when performing coordinate transfomations?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, coordinate-systems

To explain: I have two coordinate systems. One $(x,y)$ and the other $(x',y')$ as seen in this diagram. [Coordinate systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFvLc.png)

I am trying to convert the coordinate in the $(x,y)$ system to the rotated red system $(x',y')$.

I have created two equations that will convert a point in $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$ using matrices for scaling, rotation and translation.

$\begin{array}{lrrr}
x'=& x(s_x)\cos(\theta)&+~y(s_y)\sin(\theta)&+~t_x\\
y'=&-x(s_x)\sin(\theta)&+~y(s_y)\cos(\theta)&+~t_y
\end{array}$

where $\theta$ is the angle in radians, $x$ and $y$ are the original coordinates, $x'$ and $y'$ are the new coordinates, $s_x$ and $s_y$ are the scaling factors of each respective $x$ and $y$ point and $t_x$ and $t_y$ are the translation values for each point.

I have several points in the new system $(x',y')$ that can relate to the old system $(x,y)$.

However, my goal is to be able to take a point from the $(x,y)$ system and convert it to the $(x',y')$ system with a set of formulas but unfortunately, I believe that the scaling factors are different for each $(x,y)$ point depending on where it is located. I am trying to find a way to account for these changing scaling factors but I cannot find anything. I believe the translation values would be constant but my main concern is scaling. Note: I did not create this $(x',y')$ system; I have to work with it though.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The transformation you've described by your equations is a rotation and scaling, followed by a translation.  It's not clear what your question is: you have not really described the new coordinate system $(x', y')$: in the linked image it looks like a rotation only, but you've added  scaling and translation as well.  For us to help you, you need to give us more information about the new coordinate system - otherwise we're just guessing.